# Qt - How to count number of line in .txt file

Tags: qt, text-files, qfile

I want to count number of line in text file, so i can convert it to two dimensional array

The text file should be like this

```
20
30
78
1000
....
....
```

and source code using QFile to access file

```
QFile file("c:/Qt/in.txt");
file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly); //| QIODevice::Text)
y = linecount/5;
QString line[y][5];
QTextStream in(&file);
for (int k=0;k<=y;k++)
{
    for (int x=0;x<=4;x++)
    {
        line[i][x] = in.readLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: adding 4 spaces before each line of text will format it as code, so we don't have to squint our eyes to read the code..

Answer (score 5):

Your Question is not clear, and also some parameters in your code. For counting number of lines in a file, it is as simple as given below. You can use array line to populate your 2-d array.

```
QFile file("c:/Qt/in.txt");
int line_count=0;
file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly); //| QIODevice::Text)
QString line[100];
QTextStream in(&file);
while( !in.atEnd())
{
    line[line_count]=in.readLine();
    line_count++;
}
file.close();
```

Comment: Keep in mind you'll get an error if the file is over 100 lines in this example, so adjust accordingly.